# Bot lipo error in Mac PRO

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

We are developing an ios app with cocoapods. We have more than 60 pods and build times are around 1 hour using bots.

We have a Mac PRO machine with XCode 9.2  and Cocoapods 1.4.0 to build the app. The bot (archive and export ipa) fails **intermittently** while archiving. The error is related to lipo not finding a pod like this one:

*error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't move temporary file: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/a179c8572b00bdeb1f9bbce2d702aadd/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SCHEME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/somePod.framework/somePod to file: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/a179c8572b00bdeb1f9bbce2d702aadd/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SCHEME/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/somePod.framework/somePod.lipo (No such file or directory)*

The strange thing is that the error is not thrown always by the same pod. So we have different builds with lipo errors related to different pods.

Even more strange, a build using a Mac mini always works using also a bot.

We are guessing Mac Pro could be using threads in a different way than Mac Mini, but we don't have any way to check this.

Is there any limitation to lipo for large apps? Is there any configuration or tunning for the Mac Pro? Has anybody experienced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jacek Suliga (Linkedin) we realized that our pod dependency tree was not set up properly. In the Mac PRO, builds are faster and parallelization becomes more relevant than in a Mac mini. In our case, a pod was built before its pod dependencies due to this parallelization. Since parallelization depends on more items than just code, hence the intermittent build failures.

In particular, we removed some pod subspecs and created dedicated podspec files.